# ngx-formly password visibility toggle

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formly

How would I go about implementing a password visibility toggle using ngx-formly?

My model has

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
{
  template: '<div><strong>Old Password:</strong></div>',
},
{
  className: 'flex-1',
  key: 'oldPassword',
  type: 'input',
  templateOptions: {
    attributes: {
      autocomplete: 'new-username',
    },
    type: 'password',
    // label: 'Old Password',
    placeholder: 'Old Password',
    required: true,
    appearance: 'outline'
  },
},
{
  template: '<div class="mtlg"><strong>New Password:</strong></div>',
},
{
  key: 'updatedPassword',
  validators: {
    fieldMatch: {
      expression: (control) => {
        const value = control.value;
        return value.passwordConfirm === value.newPassword
          // avoid displaying the message error when values are empty
          || (!value.passwordConfirm || !value.newPassword);
      },
      message: 'Passwords do not match',
      errorPath: 'passwordConfirm',
    },
  },
  fieldGroupClassName: 'display-flex',
  fieldGroup: [
    {
      className: 'flex-2',
      key: 'newPassword',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'password',
        // label: 'Password',
        placeholder: 'Must be at least 5 characters',
        required: true,
        minLength: 5,
        appearance: 'outline'
      },
    },
    {
      template: '<div><strong>Confirm New Password:</strong></div>',
    },
    {
      className: 'flex-3',
      key: 'passwordConfirm',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'password',
        // label: 'Confirm Password',
        placeholder: 'Please re-enter your new password',
        required: true,
        appearance: 'outline'
      }
    }
  ],
}
];
```

In the old password I want to add a checkbox that if checked the type is changed from password to text so the input is visible. Do I need to create a separate checkbox or is there a method to add one within the template options of old password? I've looked in the docs but can't see this in the examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution i came up with when facing the same problem. Basically, the solution relies on creating a custom form (I was using Angular material, but it can be done for your UI framework of choice as well), extending the FieldType class:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
selector: 'formly-password-type',
template: `
<mat-form-field
  [hideRequiredMarker]="true"
  [floatLabel]="to.floatLabel"
  [appearance]="to.appearance"
  [color]="to.color"
  [style.width]="'100%'"
  [appGreyedOut]="to.readonly">

  <mat-label *ngIf="to.label && to.hideLabel !== true">
      {{ to.label }}
      <span *ngIf="to.required && to.hideRequiredMarker !== true" class="mat-form-field-required-marker">*</span>
  </mat-label>

  <input matInput #passwordField
      [id]="id"
      type="password"
      [readonly]="to.readonly"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      [tabindex]="to.tabindex || 0"
      [placeholder]="to.label">


  <mat-icon matSuffix 
    class="toggle-password"
    (click)="showHidePassword()">remove_red_eye</mat-icon>

  <mat-icon matSuffix 
    *ngIf="to.description"
    class="help-tooltip" 
    matTooltip="{{to.description}}" 
    matTooltipPosition="right">help</mat-icon>

  <mat-error [id]="null">
      <formly-validation-message [field]="field"></formly-validation-message>
  </mat-error>

  <mat-hint *ngIf="to.description" [id]="null">{{ to.description }}</mat-hint>

</mat-form-field>
`,
  styles: ['.toggle-password { color: #ccc; cursor: pointer; }']
})

export class MaterialPasswordTypeComponent extends FieldType {

    @ViewChild('passwordField', {static: false}) passwordField; 

    public showHidePassword(){
        this.passwordField.nativeElement.type = this.passwordField.nativeElement.type == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
    }
}
```

This adds an eye icon in the field, that, when clicked, changes the type of the field to text and vice-versa. Then, to use it, register this component the module of your choice, and under imports add the following:

```
FormlyModule.forRoot({
    types: [ 
        { name: 'password', component: MaterialPasswordTypeComponent }
    ]
})
```

where component is the class name of the component you created before. This will override the call to password field and will call your new password component instead.

More info on creating custom templates can be found here: [Creating a Custom Template](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field)

Comment: Awesome stuff. I'll have a proper look later when I get a chance. Thanks.